# Javascript convert uploaded image to canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need the data url of the image to be in:

```
 'data:image/jpeg;base64,""'.
```

format

So my first solution is to render the uploaded image as an Image element, and use `canvas.drawImage(imageElement)`, to get `canvas.toDataURL()`, but I'm getting the canvas has been tainted Error.

Curious is there any alternative way to get the data url of the uploaded image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a canvas. You can just use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API).

```js
const element = document.getElementById('file');
element.addEventListener('change', ({target: {files}}) => {
  const [image] = files;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = ({target: {result}}) => console.log(result);
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(image);
});
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file">
```